# Count rows in Laravel 4 database

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

Hi I am trying to get the current count of my statement below , but I am getting only the count not the whole result:

```
 $admins = DB::table('users')
    ->select(DB::raw('count(users.id) as admin_count'))
     ->where('users_roles.role_id', '=' ,0)
    ->join('users_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'users_roles.user_id')
     ->orderBy('first_name', 'asc')
    ->get();
```

Could you tell me what I am doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: You are only selecting as count.

Comment: I need to select count and the users table

Comment: What exactly you want to retrieve here? Users with admin role, simple admins count or anything else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `*` in your `SELECT` clause, and you get entire resultset. Then, `$admins` is an array, and you can get its count using `count` method.

```
$admins = DB::table('users')
    ->select('users.*')
    ->join('users_roles', 'users.id', '=', 'users_roles.user_id')
    ->where('users_roles.role_id', '=' ,0)
    ->get();
```

I assume you have `users_roles.role_id = 0` for exactly once for a user. There are no multiple entries for `role_id = 0` for one user right?

I hope this helps.

Comment: :) you were very close.

Answer (score 0):

Or you can use...

$admins = User::roles()->where('role_id', '=', 0)->count();

If the relations are setup correctly that should work.

Resource: http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#many-to-many

Comment: I m getting an error Non-static method User::roles() should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context

Comment: Which means your relations are not setup correctly.

Comment: What you mean I have this in my User.php model    public function roles()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('Role', 'users_roles');
    }

Comment: mmmm normally you do not need to provide the column, it takes id standard, so that means you have hybrid tables ?

Comment: And Role.php model public function users()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('User', 'users_roles');
    }

Comment: well you see, you have the roles there, not sure why you get that error.

Comment: From the docs... Many-to-many relations are a more complicated relationship type. An example of such a relationship is a user with many roles, where the roles are also shared by other users. For example, many users may have the role of "Admin". Three database tables are needed for this relationship: users, roles, and role_user. The role_user table is derived from the alphabetical order of the related model names, and should have user_id and role_id columns. So at your end that is users_roles, not sure if that is part of the problem but i just notice it.

Comment: Bielco, you can't use relation as staic method here.

Comment: so you are saying I have to name mine istead of users_role to role_user to make it work?>

Comment: I figured it out I could use count($admins) to get me the total admin :) easy why complicate things

Answer (score -1):

I am not sure how laravel handles nested selects with the query builder, in plain sql, it would look like this

```
SELECT users.id, (SELECT COUNT(users.id) FROM users) AS admin_count
FROM users
JOIN users_roles
ON user_roles.id = users.id
WHERE users_roles.role_id = 0
ORDER BY first_name
```

which I am pretty sure you can just assign to a variable and run it like `$admins = DB::query($sql)`

Comment: how to do it in Laravel 4

Comment: Try running that in a DB::raw call

Comment: Use eloquent orm in laravel, it does all this, without writing raw queries.

Comment: I think your missing the WHERE statement?

Comment: ahh yes the where is definitely missing, i missed that myself.

Comment: I need to select all users , do I make it users.*

Comment: users.* would select all columns from the users table not all users from the table